# Is it just me, or is adding pictures to a reply broken?

Tags: discussion

Is it just me, or is adding pictures to a reply broken?

Comment: When you say replies, do you mean comments? If so, they are supposed to be quick temporary notes for improving the questions/answers so things like displaying pictures isn't very useful.

Comment: No, I meant replies.  Imjur access was broken.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Replies aren't a thing. I'm 99% sure you mean answers now. Please make sure you are using the feature's terminology so it's easier to know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now seems to be fixed...

[image]

Comment: Yup!   How nice to get some straight answers.  I anticipated a lot more carping over netiquette!

Answer (score 5):

It's not just you.

It seems like an issue affecting the whole network.
SE staff are apparently "investigating".

See this post on meta:  [Image uploading fails with "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382854/image-uploading-fails-with-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-ser)